# Ngx-toastr - Set global config for specific toast

Tags: angular, typescript, ngx-toastr

Is there any way to set global settings for individual toast config?
I want to set this config only to error toast:

```
{
  timeOut: 0,
  extendedTimeOut: 0,
  closeButton: true
}
```

I know that I can pass those settings to individual toast like

```
this.toastService.error('ERROR', config)
```

But adding custom config to every error() call is really inconvenient. Is there a way to set those settings for error in some global config?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a wrapper service and override the default values.

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { ActiveToast, IndividualConfig, ToastrService } from 'ngx-toastr';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class CustomToastrService {
  constructor(private toastr: ToastrService) {}

  error(
    message?: string,
    title?: string,
    override?: Partial<IndividualConfig>
  ): ActiveToast<any> {
    override = {
      timeOut: 0,
      extendedTimeOut: 0,
      closeButton: true,
      ...override,
    };
    return this.toastr.error(message, title, override);
  }
}
```